# Can't execute or perform a funtion in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework, database-design

I have a syntax erro at or near ")" on executing sum function, perform doesn't work too!

That's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum() RETURNS VOID AS $$
declare
    ea bigint;
BEGIN   
FOR ea in select ean from ws_products where order_code like 'BIL%'
    LOOP
        insert into ws_products_margins (type, amount)values ('PERSENTAGE', 30.00) returning id;
        update ws_products set margin_id = id where ean = ea;
    END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

execute sum();
```

Comment: Functions are executed using `select`, procedures using `call`.

Comment: Your `INSERT` does not make sense, you are going insert the same values ('PERSENTAGE', 30.00) repeatedly with no reference to anything.  FYI, it is 'PERCENTAGE'. Also in the `UPDATE` this `margin_id = id` is not going to work as you have not captured the `id` returned from the `INSERT`. To do so see [Returnin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) `INSERT ... RETURNING expressions INTO [STRICT] target;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return that id into the variable you have declared **as rightly mentioned in the comments.**

Notice the variable name has been updated, Along with the usage of a 'record' variable.

Try-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum() RETURNS VOID AS $$
declare
    ea_id bigint;
    j record;
BEGIN   
FOR j in select ean from ws_products where order_code like 'BIL%'
    LOOP
        insert into ws_products_margins (type, amount)values ('PERCENTAGE', 30.00) returning id into ea_id;
        update ws_products set margin_id = ea_id where ean = j.ean;
    END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: The problem is you removed `ea bigint;` which means `FOR ea in ...` will no longer work. The target to `FOR` needs to be declared variable, see [Loop over Query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver **rightly mentioned**, completely slipped my attention, Thanks for pointing it out, have made the necessary corrections.